# Is there a way to make new key value paire inside of object, based on two values that are already inside of an object? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got scraper who is scraping web page for data. Object keys are: id, price, descr, link, sqm, which are made out of an arrays who are populated by scraper, and all works fine.

Object is created like this:

```
const object = ids.map((element, index) => ({
        id: element,
        price: prices[index],
        descr: descs[index],
        link: links[index],
        sqm: sqft[index],
      }));
```

now `console.log(object)` looks like:

```
[ { id: '1',
    price: '100.000 €',
    descr: 'apartment no1',
    link:
     'link to page',
    sqm: '45' },
  { id: '2',
    price: '120.000 €',
    descr: 'apartmen no2',
    link:
     'link to page',
    sqm: '42' },
  {
      ...
            },
}]
```

Now what I want to do is to add new key to the object eg. priceperm2 and take `price` and  `sqm` from object, devide those two and put it as value of priceperm2. Eg. `console.log` to now be:

```
[ { id: '1',
    price: '100.000 €',
    descr: 'apartment no1',
    link:
     'link to page',
    sqm: '45',
    priceperm2: '2222 €'},

  { id: '2',
    price: '120.000 €',
    descr: 'apartmen no2',
    link:
     'link to page',
    sqm: '42',
    priceperm2: '2857 €' },

  {
      ...
            },
}]
```

So it would be: `priceperm2` = `price/sqm` I would also to keep '€' from price. Is there some way of doing it? I've had no idea how to even start or if is it even possible. Maybe I need some kind of a loop to extract these two values, devide them and put it as new key:value pair?

Thanks!

Comment: why not store numbers without currency signs? and apply them later in the last layer?

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah I guess it will be easier. But still if there isn't currency sign how i would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```js
    const object = ids.map((element, index) => {
      const ppm2 = parseFloat(prices[index].replace(/\.| ?€$/g, '').replace(',', '.')) / parseFloat(sqft[index]);
      return {
        id: element,
        price: prices[index],
        descr: descs[index],
        link: links[index],
        sqm: sqft[index],
        priceperm2: ppm2.toFixed(2) + ' €'
      }
    });
```

On a side note, please check your object: you have the keys `sqm` and `priceperm2` (both referring to square *metres*) but the value of `sqm` is `sqft[index]` (which seems to refer to square *feets*).

Comment: One problem would be that the number is not parsed correctly. You're dealing with a European number format that has `.` as the thousands separator and `,` as the decimal separator.

Comment: Happy to help but have a look at the metres/feets issue as 1sqm = 10.7639sqft; if you calculate the price per square metre dividing the price by square feets (instead of metres) you'll get a figure that is one tenth of the actual one.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, you are right; I did not consider it. I updated the answer in order to address that issue too. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @secan this sqft[index] is in square meters not square feet. I've fixed that mistake. Code works fine, and it's correct. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
let object = [ { id: '1',
    price: '100.000 €',
    descr: 'apartment no1',
    link:
     'link to page',
    sqm: '45',},

  { id: '2',
    price: '120.000 €',
    descr: 'apartmen no2',
    link:
     'link to page',
    sqm: '42',},
];
object.forEach(obj=>{
obj.value = 30 //do whatever logic you need
})
console.log(object)
```